# How to slow down CSS animation?

Tags: css, transition

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes fader {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
#logo img.top {
    -webkit-animation-name:fader;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="logo">
    <img class="bottom" src="images/logo2.png">
    <img class="top" src="images/logo1.png">
</div>
```

PROBLEM

This crossfades two images in an infinite loop and it works wonderfully. However, the actual transition is too quick. Adjusting the duration only delays the time between the crossfade. How do I slow the fading down and not just the time between transitions?

Comment: Adjust the percentages? For example, `0%`, `30%`, `70%`, `100%`. You just have to fiddle with the percentages and the duration to get it just right.

Comment: play with -webkit-animation-delay:1s; too

Comment: Do I need to apply -moz and -o prefixes still or have those knuckleheads figured it out?

Comment: @Forever815 You must use the properties with no prefix (e.g. `animation-name`, `@keyframes`, ...). Those are the standard ones and are supported by latest browsers. Optionally, you can add `-webkit-`, `-moz-` and `-o-` prefixes for old browsers.

Comment: The `-o-` prefix was never needed but `-webkit-` was for Opera. http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation

Comment: And like mentioned in the first comment, just change the percentages : http://tinyurl.com/nbwfgdr.

Comment: Doesn't at all look like a duplicate of the question referred to. @easwee